# Blank screen and empty logs at resume time?

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, suspend, resume

I have Ubuntu 17.10 running on a custom desktop PC build (specs below). When I try to resume from suspend, I hear the fans, etc., making resume noises, but no signal to screen.

I have gotten the same result whether I suspend by using the pause button in the lock screen menu or whether I type `systemctl suspend` in a terminal.

Tried typing password, in spite of blank screen, but doesn't seem to log in. To test, I assigned a keyboard shortcut to play a sound, and the shortcut is not working after my password attempts. Therefore, sign in must not be successful. `CTRL + ALT + F1` and `CTRL + ALT + DEL` have no effect.

Tried reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times, but no success.

Tried going to Software & Updates>Additional Drivers and selecting "NVIDIA driver meta-package from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested)." System would not boot successfully after trying proprietary driver so I reinstalled Ubuntu and stayed with the open driver.

Tried suspending at a specific time, waiting five minutes, attempting to resume at a specific time, waiting five minutes, and then rebooting at a specific time. Then I checked `syslog`, `auth.log`, and `kern.log`. In those files, the logs showed activity at the time that I suspended and at the time that I rebooted, but absolutely nothing at the time that I attempted to resume.

**Computer Specs:**

- Motherboard: MSI X370 Gaming Pro Carbon
- CPU: AMD® Ryzen 7 1800x
- Graphics Card: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1050
- Graphics: NV137

I don't know what's causing the problem so I don't know how to proceed. What can I do to determine what's wrong and/or fix the problem?

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer once the question is reopened. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! I took the liberty to edit your question according to your update to *make it on topic* and remove the solution from it and then *voted to reopen* it. You can still access through the [edit history](/posts/1012239/revisions). Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by reinstalling Ubuntu, again, *and* selecting/applying the proprietary NVIDIA driver, again, via `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers`. After doing that, my system remained bootable and the resume function works properly.